# d2: default package module (like __init__.py, but for D)

Tags: package, d

Consider I have large library package with sophisticated tree of `private` or `package` modules — let's call it `funnylib`. It's not desirable for enduser to touch internal modules directly (like `funnylib.foo`, `funnylib.bar` etc), so I want to provide external interface instead — like this:

*funnylib.d:*

```
public import funnylib.foo;
public import funnylib.bar;
public import funnylib.baz;
```

to be just imported like `import funnylib` by enduser. The problem is that D disallows having `funnylib.d` and `funnylib/` at the same time.

**Is there something like "default package module" in D, like there is `__init__.py` in Python? If no, what is right way to do design described above?**

**Update1:**  I thought about moving iternal modules to package like `funnylib_private`, so `funnylib` will import fine, but this will have cost of protection lowering (strongly undesirable), as funnylib will no longer access `package` protected symbols, and will result in unpleasant file layout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot have a module and a package with the same name. So, for instance, Phobos couldn't have a `std/algorithm.d` and a `std/algorithm/sorting.d`. `std/algorithm.d` and `std/algorithm` would conflict. The typical thing to do is what [ratchet freak describes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10030449/160887) and use a module named `all` which publicly imports all of the modules within that package. But if you want to hide the fact that you're using sub-modules at all, then you could simply do something like

```
funnylib.d
_funnylib/foo.d
_funnylib/bar.d
_funnylib/baz.d
```

and not document `_funnylib` anywhere, but that doesn't work very well with ddoc, because it's going to generate the documentation for each of the `_funnylib` modules, and the most that it'll generate for `funnylib.d` is the module documentation, because it doesn't have any symbols to document. The module system is not designed with the idea that you're going to be hiding modules like you're trying to do.

Now, there *is* currently a [proposal under discussion](http://forum.dlang.org/thread/jl4gvo$2d6j$1@digitalmars.com) for making it possible to cleanly split up a module into a package when it gets too large (e.g. so that when you split up `std.algorithm` into `std.algorithm.search`, `std.algorithm.sorting`, etc. code which explicitly uses `std.algorithm.countUntil` won't break even though it's now `std.algorithm.search.countUntil`). And once that's sorted out, you could use that, but the documentation would still be done for each sub-module, not for your uber-module. It's really meant as a means of transitioning code, not trying to hide the fact that you're splitting up your modules. It's basically just the equivalent of using an `all` module but with some semantic sugar to avoid breaking code in the case where the package used to be a single module.

Comment: I don't try to hide the fact the module enduser imports is package - actually, I just want it to be clean & clear - `import funnylib;`, not `import funnylib.here_is_module_which_imports_all_other_stuff;`. So, for now I will use `funnylib.all` as temporary workaround, as if DIP16 will be accepted, this will become widely used.

Answer (score 1):

create a simple `all` module with the public imports that is documented to import the library

```
module funnylib.all;

public import funnylib.foo;
public import funnylib.bar;
public import funnylib.baz;
```

Comment: This decreases readability and makes my interface "outstanding" in negative way - why other libraries can be imported by just name, and this "special" one should be imported using `name.all`?

Comment: It is debatable. This way you can have "all" which includes all modules, "special" which includes special group of modules, "devel" which includes some new modules that are in-development, etc... I would not compare D with Python - `__init__.py` is so ugly...

Comment: `__init__` is ugly indeed, but Python allows transparently importing packages - so no `import funnylib.__init__`, which would be overkill.